# Remote PhD Using My MSc University's Lab

Tags: phd

I am currently pursuing my MSc in Applied Engineering, concentrating in Mechatronics and conducting research in cloud-based heterogeneous robotics. My current university does not have a PhD program for engineering.

Are there universities that would allow me to remotely enroll in their PhD program and conduct my research using my current university's equipment?

Comment: Why would your current university destine equipment an space to someone working for another university? And what if the university you apply for has actually _better_ equipment?

Comment: My university would be happy to allow me to use the equipment to conduct PhD research. I've already expressed this interest to my research advisor, and he was looking into it but is buried in committee and paperwork stuff for awhile.

Better equipment would certainly be fun to work with, but my MSc is only scratching the surface of what can be done in my current lab, and I'm really eager to continue work here.

Comment: You could look into doing a jointly supervised project. Your MSc supervisor and someone else from another institution could both supervise the project. You might be able to spend some time at the other institution and use their lab facilities too.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the country and the PhD program.

In the UK, you could look for a relevant supervisor in nearby universities (e.g. a couple of hours drive away) who might be interested in your proposed project and might be able to fund it (even if you don't need lab space, you'd pay fees etc). You would probably need to meet with them (and other academic supervisors / trainers) every quarter, with more frequent email / phone / video contact - depending on the particular universities rules & regulations. I've seen lots of people do these sort of multi-site projects.